# Live folders for Contact groups?

Tags: contacts, home-screen-folders

Does anyone know of an app which will allow you to place live folders on your home screen which are tied to a specific contact group? That is, when setting it up you would choose a group from your address book, and it would then show you all the contacts in that group, when opened.

I tried this app: [Groupie](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/groupie_bdgp.html), but it has a number of problems. The groups it lists are NOT the groups that are in my contacts (it seems to only list some common groups, but not the ones actually in my contacts). Even for a group with the same name as one in my contacts, it does not actually show any contacts when I clicked on the folder. 
Plus, *while admittedly minor*, the icon for the folders is dorky.  ;)  Ideally would like one that uses a variation on the standard live folder icons (like **All Contacts**, **Contacts with Phone Numbers**, **Received from Bluetooth** and **Starred Contacts**)

Running on a Galaxy S Captivate, unrooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, ... there was no app that I could find that would do this. So, I wrote one. It actually uses home screen shortcuts, not live folders, due to the way they are implemented and the complexity of coding them.

If anyone should be interested, I've since rewritten it... you can find the new one here: [Live Groups](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.eidylon.livegroups.lite).

Answer (score 3):

Dunno if this has gotten answered, but had to deal with this today and the app Groupy is great.  you can even hide groups so it lists only the ones you want, it handles multiple accounts setup on the phone just fine, and I know for sure if you drop a shortcut to the app itself it will open right up once you tap the 1x1 shortcut on the desktop right to the listing of the groups.

It also has some nice shortcut buttons to send an Email, SMS [or MMS] right from that listing screen [the icons are right across the bottom of the screen when the app is open.

I didn't see any widgets listed under widgets for it, but I haven't gone extremely in-depth with it yet.  I don't see a major need for them as when you tap the app shortcut the app opens right to a list of all the groups you have on the device [be they system, or created by you the user (if done via google contacts website be sure to either wait for the sync or go in to settings accounts and tap the account you modified contacts on and tap to clear then tap to add the checkmark back as that will cause it to sync right away [or of course hit sync now button if you have that available instead if you prefer]).
Of course if you go through and choose to hide any groups when you open the app it will only list that groups that have not been hidden.

You can even choose multiple groups to send messages to by tapping the checkboxes found on the right hand side of the screen for all the groups you want to send your message to.

**PLEASE BE AWARE FOR BOTH EMAIL AND SMS OR MMS:** Some carriers/providers do put limits on how many contacts you may send any one message to in attempts to curtail people from spamming too many people at once.  You will need to review the limits with your carrier in the case of SMS/MMS messages OR you provider for your email account for emails.
So if your groups [or groups] contain too many people your message may either fail to send at all or only send to soo many people [depending on how your carrier/service provider choose to handle the limit]

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of any way to do this automatically, aside from some app I don't know of, but you can do it yourself by adding a new blank folder and then adding shortcuts to your contacts in it however you like.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as You. I don't remember how I resolved it on my Wildfire S.
I only know, that I installed something like "Group manager", but couldn't find it anymore, and missing it after factory reset of the phone. But I'm not sure, if advantage of making "group shortcut" was made by this APP, because I've tried some other APPs.
There was one file manger and so....
And about Your App. Not bad, usefull. But on my Wildfire S is slow. I think it's because of pic thumbnails. App I've used before showed only names and numbers.
If You will rewrite Your App, I can write You some hints.
Or if You want, please write me how did You make it. I'm older, but have young son, which can continue or make it with You.

Regards

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please note that this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: As Al said, this doesn't really answer the question, and would've been better as a comment. Interesting point about the thumbnails... I will add to my to-do list to make an option for viewing as a list without thumbnails.